# Bar chart not getting plotted in python. Error "no numeric data to plot"

Tags: python, bar-chart

```
import requests
import json
import io
import pandas as pd
import array as arr
from functools import reduce
import urllib3
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

url="https://ankurtestpython.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/search"
headers={
  "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

query = {
   'jql': 'project = testpython and type = Story and labels = demo-desk'
}

response=requests.get(url,headers=headers,params=query,auth=("XXX@gmail.com","xBtS2a68ffUTvV4uuX69I4jEjR2doUg3r8TVpevcH6N5MkyBe_rlI1dvLzu2F6IPGsU_m0LbZsenHtmU0WZKOB_b2qaU-idPglSE6AwhkhQ_MEuD0=4BC543C6"))
data=response.json()

issues=data["issues"]
arr=[]
arr2=[]
arr3=[]
Total=0
result2 = []

for issue in issues:
    arr=[issue["key"],issue["fields"]["issuetype"]["name"]]
    arr2.append(arr)
    arr=[]
    arr3.append(issue["fields"]["status"]["name"])

unique, counts = np.unique(arr3, return_counts=True)
res = counts.astype(str)

for i in counts:
    Total+=i
result = reduce(lambda res, l: res + [l[0] + "," + l[1]], zip(unique, res), [])

for word in result:
    word = word.split(",")
    result2.append(word)

df = pd.DataFrame(result2,columns=['Status','Count'])
print(df)
plt = df.plot.bar(x='Status', y='Count', rot=70)
```

Below is the result i get when I execute `print(df)`

[image]

But when I try to plot bar chart using below commands, I get an error stating
"no numeric data to plot"

```
df = pd.DataFrame(result2,columns=['Status','Count'])
plt = df.plot.bar(x='Status', y='Count', rot=70)
```

Comment: Since you got the data as JSON, are Count values actually `int` or are they `str`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dataframe columns are not in a numeric format, and thus cannot be plotted as a bar chart. In your code, it appears that the values in the Count column are in string format, not numeric.

To resolve this error, you can convert the Count column to a numeric format before plotting the bar chart. You can do this using the astype() method in Pandas to convert the column to an integer or float format.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(result2,columns=['Status','Count'])
df['Count'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Count'])  <== Convert Count column to numeric format
plt = df.plot.bar(x='Status', y='Count', rot=70)
```

Comment: Thanks This helped. I investigated and found the count was still STR. Thanks